# Why does pushing space bar not put a value in array?

Tags: c, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){ 
    printf("Enter 10 numbers: ");
    int a[10], i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }
}
```

When I put value in each array, why pushing the space bar can put a value in the array?

For example when I write 1<kbd>space</kbd>2<kbd>space</kbd>3<kbd>space</kbd> then each value is put in each array (a[0], a[1], a[2]).

Why is this happening?

Comment: What would you expect to happen instead?

Comment: Did you read the spec on scanf(). E.g. http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf

Comment: @jimmm  It is a fantastic!

Comment: I just want know what role doe space have.. . Anyway I got a answer thanks.

Comment: Please check that what the question now says is more or less what you intended it to say.  However, I'm still confused about what you are puzzled about? Values aren't sent to the program for processing until you hit the return key; you won't see any data in the array until after the return is hit. If you put one number per line, you'll hit the return key 10 times; if you stack them up on a single line with spaces in between, you may only need to hit return once. The final newline will be left in the buffer for the subsequent input. Check that `scanf()` succeeds — `if (scanf("%d", &a[i]) != 1)`

Comment: It is unclear whether you're confused about (a) how standard-input line buffering can work, or (b) how formatted input reads skip whitespace.

Comment: I was confused about this at first as well. It seems OP is expecting that pressing `space` should effectively be the same as pressing `return` for each number.  Does someone know if I'm wrong in saying that `scanf` reads the string entered before pressing `return`, then parses through it according to the format symbol? e.g. OP is entering the following string `"1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0\n\r"`, then scanf (using format `%d`) linearly iterates through that string and when it finds a substring of digits surrounded by a separator, it places it in the array?

Comment: @jimmm The only answer I can give now is “It inserts the space character, separating the numbers”. I expect that’s not actually useful; could you please clarify what about the behavior is confusing? Are you surprised that you need to press space and thing that entering “1234567890” should have the same behavior? Are you confused that it returns more than the first number on the line? Where, specifically, does the behavior differ from your expectations; what input gives a different result than you’d expect?

Comment: @Daniel H I just know what function does space bar has.  I didn't confused about something. Is this question ambiguous enough to confuse you? then i'm sorry .. when i ask next time, i will think thoroughly. .

Comment: @jimmm If you know what function the space has in the expression, then why are you asking what function the space has in the expression? Yes, the question is ambiguous to be confusing, which is why I and WhozCraig ask what you mean, and why Jonathan Leffler and galois thought you meant different things. That’s why I asked the clarifying questions.

Comment: @Daniel H I missed 'want'..// I just want know what function does space bar has/// this was my first question.. sorry ㅠㅠㅠ

Comment: @jimmm I’m not asking for an apology; you’re new and asking good questions is a skill. If you understood the design and behavior of `scanf` at least in regards to spaces in the input, then there’s no need to ask questions about it. My questions were asking you to get more specific. Do you understand the behavior of `scanf` but are wondering why it was designed that way; if so, what alternative design would you compare it to? Do you not understand the behavior of `scanf`, in which case what specific behavior don’t you understand?

Comment: @jimmm: It's not that the space bar itself has a specific function - you'd get the same result if you used the Tab or Enter keys.  It's the fact that you introduce *whitespace* between the three numbers - that splits them into three separate inputs as far as `scanf` is concerned.

Comment: @Daniel H I think this question is caused by a lack of understanding the behavior of scanf. I didn't understand that when i use scanf, what function can seperate each value. so i asked this question. and i got answer. (Next time i will ask  more specific question).

Comment: @jimmm If you found one of the answers below good, you should click the checkmark under the voting buttons to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the C Standard (7.21.6.2 The fscanf function)

12 The conversion specifiers and their meanings are:

```
d   Matches an optionally signed decimal integer, whose format is the same as
    expected for the subject sequence of the strtol function with the value 10
    for the base argument. The corresponding argument shall be a pointer to
    signed integer.
```

And (7.22.1.4 The strtol, strtoll, strtoul, and strtoull functions)

> 2. ...First, they decompose the input string into three parts: an initial, possibly empty, sequence of white-space characters (as
>      specified by the isspace function), a subject sequence resembling an
>      integer represented in some radix determined by the value of base, and
>      a final string of one or more unrecognized characters, including the
>      terminating null character of the input string. Then, they attempt to
>      convert the subject sequence to an integer, and return the result.

For such an input

1`space`2`space`3`space`
the first *subject sequence* is 1, the second *subject sequence* (after skipping white-space characters) is 2, and the third *subject sequence* is 3. They are used to store integers correspondingly in a[0], a[1], and a[2] because each *subject sequence* represents a valid integer.

Take into account that in general implementations use the so-called *line buffering* for text streams.

From the C Standard (7.21.3 Files)

> 3. ... When a stream is line buffered, characters are intended to be 
>      transmitted to or from the host environment as a block **when a
>      new-line character is encountered**.

Comment: Nice answer, I don't understand why I am thus far the only upvoter. Btw, ain't it about time you found a job ;-) ? The financial services industry is crying out for capable C++ developers.

Answer (score -2):

As you are using scanf() with %d, the input stream is accepting integer values, and considering others as separator.

Comment: Only whitespace is a separator.

Comment: White space, tab, enter... all are separators

Comment: Those are all called whitespace. But your answer makes it sound like anything other than digits would be a separator, which is not true.

Comment: For example, `,` isn’t a separator, but from just your answer I’d expect it to be.

Comment: @interjay: from the perspective of the `%d` conversion specifier, *any* non-decimal-digit character marks the end of the input, whitespace or not.

Comment: `"%d"` does not consider leading white-space as a reason to stop scanning.  A single `'-'`, `'+'` is OK too.   (white-spaces)(+-)[digits] is accepted, after that, scanning stops

Comment: @JohnBode Marks the end of the input, yes. But “separator” implies it can separate two different values. If you enter `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0` into the program in the question, it won’t work.